# Apple Push notification with PHP via proxy

Tags: php, proxy, apple-push-notifications

I need to connect to Apple PNS via proxy. I am using PHP to develop the application. Currently, I have googled a lot but nowhere I am able to find an example of using Proxy with stream context. 
Also did the steps mentioned here:
[Using Charles and SSL Apple push address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154235/using-charles-and-ssl-apple-push-address)

Below is the code snippet. Anyone please suggest, its highly urgent

```
if(PROXY_ADDRESS != '' && PROXY_PORT !='')
{       
$opts = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://'.PROXY_ADDRESS.':'.PROXY_PORT, 'request_fulluri' => true));
$streamContext = stream_context_create($opts);
}
else
{
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
}

stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->_privateKey);

if($this->_privateKeyPassphrase !== '')
  stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $this->_privateKeyPassphrase);

$fp = fopen('https://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', 'r', false, $streamContext);
```

I am not getting any error/exception, but the push message is not received.

Comment: Are you sure your error reporting is turned on?

Comment: yes, it is turned on.

Comment: I also came across these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524971/ping-to-apns-not-returning. Is it really true?

Comment: What happens if you speficically use an incorrect URL. Are you seeing any errors then? Have you tried `fread()` ing some data from `$fp`? What value is `$fp`?

Comment: $fp is returned as false

Comment: Then you have an error in `fopen()` which is not being displayed. Are you sure all error reporting is on, and `display_errors` as well?

Answer (score 0):

To those who may encounter the same problem:

Apple PNS doesn't allow connections coming via Proxy Server. It only accepts direct connections. My problem got resolved when I made a direct connection instead of going via a proxy.

Comment: Where can we find documentation about connecting via server to apns?